# Object reference not set to an instance of an object error with list arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to initialize a `List<string>` array and while I have looked at other resources trying them made my compiler throw errors all the time.

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350940/list-array-initialization-c-sharp), but it did not help.

My code is:

```
List<string>[] list = new List<string>[3];
list[1].Add("text");
```

I get the error on the second line. I have tried:

```
List<string>[] list = new List<string>[3]();
List<string>[] list = new List<string>()[3];
List<string>[] list = new List<string>()
{
   new string("hh"),
   new string("gg")
};
List<string>[] list = new List<string>()
{
   "hh",
   "gg"
};
```

But none of these work.

Comment: [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Do you want a list of strings or an array of lists of strings?

Comment: List<string>[] list = new List<string>[3]; creates an array of 3 lists of string. If you just want data storage for string you can go with List<string> list = new List<string>(); and add values via list.Add("exampleStringValue");

Comment: @Charleh, an array of lists of strings. x...'s answer is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @PaulWeiland, that is exactly what I do not want, but thanks, anyway!

Comment: @JonSkeet, I disagree that my question is a duplicate of that one, it certainly explains a lot about null exceptions (and well), but my problem was more along the lines of I didn't know how to properly initialize an array of List<string>

Comment: It is a duplicate as is - if you'd asked "why is my array being initialized with null references" it wouldn't have been... but that question is basically useful for questions which show a lack of knowledge of what causes a NullReferenceException.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  List<string>[] list = new List<string>[3];
  list[0] = new List<string>();
  list[1] = new List<string>();
  list[2] = new List<string>();
  list[1].Add("text");
```